# Youtube Live API - Insert broadcast returns Insufficient scope error for sometime

Tags: youtube-data-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

After creating few successful youtube live broadcasts, I started getting 403 error with following in the response.

```
 { status code: 403, headers {
    "Cache-Control" = "private, max-age=0";
    "Content-Encoding" = gzip;
    "Content-Length" = 225;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";
    Date = "Mon, 06 Mar 2017 11:46:15 GMT";
    Expires = "Mon, 06 Mar 2017 11:46:15 GMT";
    Server = GSE;
    Vary = "Origin, X-Origin";
    "Www-Authenticate" = "Bearer realm=\"https://accounts.google.com/\", error=insufficient_scope, scope=\"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube\"";
    "alt-svc" = "quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"36,35,34\"";
    "x-content-type-options" = nosniff;
    "x-frame-options" = SAMEORIGIN;
    "x-xss-protection" = "1; mode=block";
}
```

My app got the ["/auth/youtube", "/auth/youtube.upload", "/auth/youtube.force-ssl", "/auth/youtube.readonly"] permissions from the user.

I have verified this with oauth2/token_info end point of Google API explorer. My access token is valid and has all required permissions.

This happened to me 2 days ago. But it started working a couple of hours. This again started happening.

The same API is working at the same time for a different account. I logged out of google and got a new access token but the issue still exists.